# Compiling jrtplib with MSVC with /MT flag

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I am using the provided CMakeLists.txt file which contains the code above. What I am trying to do is to compile the library using the /MT flag. Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Here the code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(jrtplib)
set(VERSION 3.9.1)

 SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/nologo /W3 /GX /Gy /YX")
       SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Z7 /Od")
       SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2")
       SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "/MT /O2")
       SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "/MTd /Z7 /Od")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib32/" AND CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib32)
elseif (EXISTS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64/" AND CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib64)
endif ()

set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "${_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}" CACHE PATH "Library installation directory")
if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}")
    set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}")
endif()

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
include(TestBigEndian)
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Macros.cmake)

find_package(JThread)

set(JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "")
set(JRTPLIB_INTERNAL_INCLUDES "")
set(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES "")

add_additional_stuff(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS)

jrtplib_support_option("Support SDES PRIV items" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_SDESPRIV RTP_SUPPORT_SDESPRIV ON "// No support for SDES PRIV items")
jrtplib_support_option("Support the probation mechanism for a new source" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_PROBATION RTP_SUPPORT_PROBATION ON "// Do not wait for a number of consecutive packets to validate source")
jrtplib_support_option("Support sending RTCP APP packets" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_SENDAPP RTP_SUPPORT_SENDAPP ON "// No direct support for sending RTCP APP packets")
jrtplib_support_option("Support sending unknown RTCP packets" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_RTCPUNKNOWN RTP_SUPPORT_RTCPUNKNOWN OFF "// No support for sending unknown RTCP packets")
jrtplib_support_option("Support memory management mechanism" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_MEMORYMGMT RTP_SUPPORT_MEMORYMANAGEMENT ON "// No memory management support")

jrtplib_include_test(sys/filio.h RTP_HAVE_SYS_FILIO "// Don't have <sys/filio.h>")
jrtplib_include_test(sys/sockio.h RTP_HAVE_SYS_SOCKIO "// Don't have <sys/sockio.h>")
jrtplib_include_test(ifaddrs.h RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS "// No ifaddrs support")

if (JTHREAD_FOUND)
    set(V "ON")
else (JTHREAD_FOUND)
    set(V "OFF")
endif (JTHREAD_FOUND)

option(JTHREAD_ENABLED "Thread support" ${V})
if (JTHREAD_ENABLED)
    set (RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD "#define RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD")
    if (JTHREAD_FOUND)
        save_paths(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES "${JTHREAD_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
        save_paths(JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "${JTHREAD_LIBRARIES}")
    endif(JTHREAD_FOUND)
else (JTHREAD_ENABLED)
    set (RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD "// No support for JThread was enabled")
endif (JTHREAD_ENABLED)

if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    option (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN "Target platform is big endian" ON)
    if (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "#define RTP_BIG_ENDIAN")
    else (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "// Little endian system")
    endif (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
else (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    test_big_endian(JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
    if (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "#define RTP_BIG_ENDIAN")
    else (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "// Little endian system")
    endif (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
endif (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)

jrtplib_test_feature(socklentest RTP_SOCKLENTYPE_UINT TRUE "// socklen_t is 'int'")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv4mcasttest RTP_SUPPORT_IPV4MULTICAST FALSE "// No IPv4 multicasting support")
jrtplib_test_feature(salentest RTP_HAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN FALSE "// No sa_len member in struct sockaddr")
jrtplib_test_feature(getloginrtest RTP_SUPPORT_GETLOGINR FALSE "// Not using getlogin_r")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv6test RTP_SUPPORT_IPV6 FALSE "// No IPv6 support")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv6mcasttest RTP_SUPPORT_IPV6MULTICAST FALSE "// No IPv6 multicasting support")

check_cxx_source_compiles("#include <stdint.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\nint main(void) { size_t a = 0 ; size_t b = a; uint32_t x = 0; uint32_t y = x; return 0; }" JRTPLIB_STDINT)
if (JRTPLIB_STDINT)
    set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include <stdint.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>")
else (JRTPLIB_STDINT)
    check_cxx_source_compiles("#include <inttypes.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\nint main(void) { uint32_t x = 0; uint32_t y = x; return 0; }" JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
    if (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
        set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include <inttypes.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\n")
    else (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
        if (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
            set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include \"rtptypes_win.h\"")
        else (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
            set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#error Could not find header files that define types like 'uint32_t'. Please edit the file ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes_unix.h and make sure that the following types are defined: int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t")
            message("\n\nError: Could not find header files that define types like 'uint32_t'.\nPlease edit the file ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes_unix.h\nand make sure that the following types are defined: \nint8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t\n\n")
        endif (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
    endif (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
endif (JRTPLIB_STDINT)

if (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
    set(RTP_WINSOCK_HEADERS "#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)\n    #include <winsock2.h>   \n  #include <ws2tcpip.h>\n#ifndef _WIN32_WCE\n #include <sys/types.h>\n#endif // _WIN32_WCE\n#endif // WIN32 || _WIN32_WCE\n")
endif (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)

if (NOT UNIX)
    set(JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "Flag indicating if a static library should be built, or a dynamic one")
    list(APPEND JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "ws2_32")
endif (NOT UNIX)

if (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_IMPORT "")
    set(JRTPLIB_EXPORT "")
else (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_IMPORT "__declspec(dllimport)")
    set(JRTPLIB_EXPORT "__declspec(dllexport)")
endif (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)

configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rtptypes.h.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes.h")
configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rtpconfig.h.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtpconfig.h")

save_paths(JRTPLIB_INTERNAL_INCLUDES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src")

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(examples)

if (UNIX)
    get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared LOCATION)
    get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME)
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME}")
else (UNIX)
    if (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-static RELEASE_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-static DEBUG_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
    else (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared RELEASE_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared DEBUG_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
    endif (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS optimized "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE}.lib" 
                 debug "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG}.lib")
endif (UNIX)

set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS ${JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
set(JRTPLIB_LIBS ${JRTPLIB_LIBS} ${JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS})
remove_empty(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES JRTPLIB_INCDIRS)
remove_empty(JRTPLIB_LIBS)

foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_LIBS})
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS_CMAKECONFIG "${JRTPLIB_LIBS_CMAKECONFIG} \"${ARG}\"")
endforeach()
foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS})
    set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_CMAKECONFIG "${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_CMAKECONFIG} \"${ARG}\"")
endforeach()

configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake")
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake" DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIB)

if (UNIX)
    foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_LIBS})
        set(JRTPLIB_LIBS_PKGCONFIG "${JRTPLIB_LIBS_PKGCONFIG} ${ARG}")
    endforeach()
    foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS})
        set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_PKGCONFIG "${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_PKGCONFIG} -I${ARG}")
    endforeach()

    configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc)
    install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/pkgconfig)
endif (UNIX)
```

Comment: When you don't know how to hack cmake scripts then just don't bother.  Run it to generate the project file, open it in Visual Studio and use Project + Properties to change the setting.

Comment: That's just what I am trying to learn: how to hack cmake scripts. The point is that the .sln and cxproj files that creates the cmake script is specific for CMake or something, and it just provide the following fields in Configuration Properties: General, Debugging, VC++ Directories, Build Events, and Custom Build Tool, no more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding flags to CMAKE_C_FLAGS and friends is the proper way to pass specific flags to the compiler, but the CMAKE_C_* variables only affect compilation of C files.

If you have any C++ files in the project, you'll also need to set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and friends.

Also, you can do this without modifying the CMakeLists file, in cmake-gui or ccmake. After configuring once, you can see the default values for these variables in cmake-gui or ccmake. Then, you can change some of the variables directly in the app, configure again, and voila: you've set the flags for your build tree without modifying any code.

If you always want the flags, then modifying the code is the right approach. But if you're just trying to get a build done, you can set the flags without touching the code.